# How to access the reference to the head node in this doubly linked list?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list

```
reference data types:

class DLLNode:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None

class DLList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
```

```
class Solution:
    def sortedInsert(self, head, D):
```

I tried to access the head node's reference but it doesn't seem to work. What is the mistake that I'm doing here?

My Attempt:

```
class Solution:
    def sortedInsert(self, head, D):
        itr = head
        while itr:
            print(itr.val)
            itr = itr.next
        return head
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 107, in <module>
    retval = Solution().sortedInsert( head, D )
  File "main.py", line 86, in sortedInsert
    print(itr.val)
AttributeError: 'DLList' object has no attribute 'val'
```

Comment: Where is your attempt, and what error did you get when you tried it?

Comment: Edited. Please check now.

Comment: The `head` variable is a `DLList`, not a `DLNode`, so you'll have to set `itr = head.head` instead of `itr = head`, probably.

Comment: Thank you. It worked